# Do I have to import the class if an instance of the class will be used in Python?

Tags: python, import, module

I am using PRAW. In my code, an instance of a class in PRAW is declared in a module and return. Do I have to import the class or PRAW in my main module to be able to use its sub methods and variables?

Comment: Well, why did you not simply try it out?

Comment: My code is very complicated and it is called occasionally. Since Python has a lot of tricks, I though it would be great idea to ask the community and expect some good advice or warnings rather than a "yes" or "no".

Comment: `import` does two things: (1) If the module has not yet been executed, it executes it. This doesn't matter for your case, because obviously if you're getting instances from the module, it's been executed. (2) It gives you a name that you can use to reference to the module. This doesn't matter for your case, because you have no need to name the class or anything else defined in the module. So, no, don't import it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wish you post it as an answer. Yet, I still don't understand why am I getting downvotes. I didn't get single google result when I searched for it. I though I could provide some resources if I would post it to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

If you have an instance of some class, the definition of that class is already lying somewhere in the Python process - if it was defined in a module (in contrast with dynamically constructed using `type`), that module was imported somewhere else, and the class definition can be found there.

The "import" mechanism in Python is quite efficient, so if you do import a module that is not yet loaded into the current process, its code is actually run. Afterwards, a reference to that module is kept in a central registry, which is exposed in the `sys.modules` dictionary (that is a plain dictionary in the `sys` module).

Whenever new module imports, or name imports from modules that are already present there take place, all that Python does is to assign a variable in the scope  the import is taking place, referring to the object already in memory - so, `import` on an "already known" object is just an assignment, quite the same thing the "=" symbol performs.

But when you have an instance of a class, it already contains a reference to its class, there is no need to bring it into the current namespace. (That reference is on the instance's `__class__` attribute, btw).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was seeking for an answer like that.

Comment: If the answer is satisfactory, please check it as accepted.